# Два-три деревья

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Решил изучить [2-3 деревья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Встала задача реализации. У меня получилось так

```
class TTTNode {
public:
    TTTNode() : first(NULL), second(NULL), third(NULL),
        value(-1), secondValue(-1), thirdValue(-1) {}
    TTTNode(int val) : first(NULL), second(NULL), third(NULL),
        value(val), secondValue(-1), thirdValue(-1) {}
    bool isLeaf() { return first == NULL && second == NULL && third == NULL && value != -1; }
    bool isPreLeaf() {
        bool f,s,th;
        if (first != NULL) 
            f = first->isLeaf();
        else 
            f = true;
        if (second != NULL)
            s = second->isLeaf();
        else 
            s = true;
        if (third != NULL)
            th = third->isLeaf();
        else 
            th = true;
        return f && s && th;
    }
public:
    TTTNode * first;
    TTTNode * second;
    TTTNode * third;
    int value;
    int secondValue;
    int thirdValue;
};

class TTT {/* TwoThreeTree */
public:
    TTT() : root(NULL) {}
    void insertValue( int value);
    void deleteValue( int value);
    bool findValue(int value);
private:
    TTTNode * _makeRoot(int value) ;
    TTTNode * _make(int value);
    bool _find(TTTNode * node, int value);
    TTTNode * _findMountNode(TTTNode * node, int value);
    void _insert(TTTNode * node, int value) ;
private:
    TTTNode * root;
};
```

Мне кажется, что я слишком усложнил реализацию. Имеется в виду TTTNode. Может можно проще описать отношение потомков и значений, хранящихся в узле?

Comment: А где, собственно, сама реализация? Когда я писал 2,3-деревья, то у меня вышло примерно 1200 строк кода на Си

Comment: @saigono Думаю, не самое лучшее выкладывать сюда реализацию. Вопрос не об реализации методов, а об улучшении TTTNode, как структуры данных.

Answer (score 1):

Вызывает смущение тот факт, что у вас в одной структуре смешаны и 2-узлы и 3-узлы. Почему бы не сделать абстрактный интерфейс для узлов типа:

```
struct node
{
bool isLeaf() const = 0;
bool isPreLeaf() const = 0;
...........
};
```

И отнаследовать 2-узлы и 3-узлы от него.

Таким образом вы избежите путаницы в методах. Ведь в вашем случае у Вас в каждом методе должен быть if определяющий, что надо работать с 2-узлом или с 3-узлом. Т.е. каждый метод будет по факту содержать два. Запутаться будет не проблема.

Comment: Интересная мысль.